# Is IRS dual-status optional?

Tags: united-states, irs, foreign-income, dual-status

In 2019 I was a resident US alien for IRS purposes. In September I permanently moved out of the US. Thereafter, I got a job in the foreign country and received foreign salary for the last months of 2019.

According to this [IRS guidance](https://www.irs.gov/publications/p519#en_US_2019_publink1000222182), it seems I qualify for dual status taxation (resident until I left and non-resident afterwards). However, I would prefer to file as resident for the whole year (since it seems the paperwork is significantly simpler and I'm allowed to use the standard deduction). My question is am I allowed to do that?

Bonus question: Assuming filing as resident is OK and I want to avoid paying tax on my foreign income, am I allowed to use the [Foreign Earned Income Exclusion](https://www.irs.gov/individuals/international-taxpayers/foreign-earned-income-exclusion)? This is assuming I file taxes in October and satisfy the [physical presence test](https://www.irs.gov/individuals/international-taxpayers/foreign-earned-income-exclusion-physical-presence-test) by that time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are considered a resident alien the whole year by default. You are a resident alien because you pass the Substantial Presence Test for the year. There are [Last Year of Residency](https://www.irs.gov/publications/p519#en_US_2019_publink1000222182) rules in which you can elect to have your residency termination date changed to when you left the US, but that is something you have to elect and attach a signed statement to your tax return in order to invoke. If you don't do that, you will be a resident alien for the whole year.

Yes, I believe you can use the Foreign Earned Income Exclusion once you pass the Physical Presence Test by finding a 12-month period during which you were outside the US for at least 330 days.